# React: Unable to call `setList` (a `useState` hook) from a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm encountering an issue while trying to call the `setList` function (which is a `useState` hook) from a child component in React. React is giving me the following error: "TypeError: setList is not a function."

Here's the code for my parent component:

```js
import React, { memo, useState } from "react";
import { Dustbin } from "./Dustbin";
import { Box } from "./Box";

export const Container = memo(function Container() {
  const { list, setList } = useState();

  const handleDrop = (item) => {
    console.log("dropped", item);
    setList(item);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ overflow: "hidden", clear: "both" }}>
        <Dustbin list={list} />
      </div>
      <div style={{ overflow: "hidden", clear: "both" }}>
        <Box name="Glass" handleDrop={handleDrop} />
        <Box name="Banana" handleDrop={handleDrop} />
        <Box name="Paper" handleDrop={handleDrop} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
```

And here's the code for my child component (Box):

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";
import { ItemTypes } from "./ItemTypes";

const style = {
  border: "1px dashed gray",
  backgroundColor: "white",
  padding: "0.5rem 1rem",
  marginRight: "1.5rem",
  marginBottom: "1.5rem",
  cursor: "move",
  float: "left"
};

export const Box = ({ name, handleDrop }) => {
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag({
    item: { name, type: ItemTypes.BOX },
    end: (item, monitor) => {
      const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
      if (item && dropResult) {
        handleDrop({ pippo: item.name }); // The call causing the error
        console.log(item);
      }
    },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    })
  });

  const opacity = isDragging ? 0.4 : 1;

  return (
    <div ref={drag} style={{ ...style, opacity }}>
      {name}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing here and why I'm unable to call `setList` from the child component? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState returns an Array not object,

instead of

```
const { list, setList } = useState();
```

do

```
const [list, setList ] = useState();
```